# bootstrap css overidden by my css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm facing a strange problem, most of the questions I see are Bootstrap CSS are overwriting my CSS but I'm facing the opposite problem.

> My CSS classes are overwriting Bootstrap classes.

Sequence of CSS files are mycss, then boostrap and yet my CSS classes are overwriting Bootstrap classes.

Bootstrap objects like Datetime controls are not rendering properly. My CSS classes are huge and they are used across multiple projects. Any advise please?

[image]

Comment: For better suggestion it will be great if you can share the scenario by uploading markup or URL?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you use same class names as Bootstrap. If you don't override Bootstrap classes nor extend their attributes you should rename your own ones.